# Syncing time of multiple devices using BLE

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing an application in which i have to sync time of multiple devices without giving application root access. Since i can't programmatically change the time of device on android without getting root access, i have one device acting as the true source of time and other devices need to somehow connect to it and get the time and save the local offset.

For this purpose i am using Bluetooth low energy. The master device plays the peripheral role where it advertises a custom service containing the characteristic 'current time', and other devices acting as centrals will look for that advertisement, connect with master, read the current time. So far i have only been able to make it work for one peripheral and one central.

Can a peripheral device connect to multiple central devices, if so then what is the limit to the number of connections?

Is there a better way to address this use case of syncing time of multiple devices?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit SoC specific, but you should check out this blog:
https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/b/blog/posts/wireless-timer-synchronization-among-nrf5-devices

A max jitter of 220ns over a 30min period is quite an achievement. Although it does not use BLE, but proprietary 2.4GHz the idea can be applied for BLE as well, but not with the same performance.